# Codename One iOS 64-bit performance

Tags: ios, performance, 64-bit, codenameone, iphone-x

My app contains a multithreaded engine that plays a game which can be compared to chess.
It performs a lot of bitwise operations (shift, and, etc.) on 64-bit words.
On a PC the 64-bit version is much faster than the 32-bit version, and on a recent phone/tablet you would expect the same.
The table below contains some test results (best result is 100, less means slower).
The benchmark consists of adding the numbers 1 through 200 million in parallel. I verified that 4 threads is faster than 2 or 1.

```
hardware           os      build         threads benchmark search task
----------------------------------------------------------------------
MacBook            Windows 64-bit JVM       4          100         100
MacBook            Windows CN1 Simulator    4          100          42
iPhone X           iOS     debug armv7      4           14           2
iPhone X           iOS     debug arm64      4           14           2
Samsung Tab A 10.1 Android debug            4            8           1
Samsung Tab A 10.1 Android release          4           10           7
```

Observations:

1. On the MacBook the search task is performed more than twice as slow in the simulator compared to a normal 64-bit JVM.
   Presumably this is because there is no (native) support for the functions Long.bitCount() and Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(),
   which I had to replace by (slower) code. Question: is there a way to improve this?
2. There is no difference between the iPhone X armv7 and arm64 builds. How is this possible? (I tried removing the app and
   restarting the phone before installing the arm64 version. The current AppStore version is 32-bit, IIRC.)
3. The Android release version does a much better job on the search task than the debug version: 7 times faster!

On the Samsung Tab the performance is satisfactory, on the iPhone X I would say it is below par.
Comparing the CPUs (iPhone X: 64-bit 6-core @ 2.39 & 1.42 GHz, Samsung Tab A 10.1: 64-bit 8-core @ 1.6 GHz)
the iPhone X should not be 3.5 times slower (score 2 vs 7).

To be sure, I looked at the iOS arm64 debug build ipa with the MacOS 'file' command and it says: Mach-0 64-bit executable.

So I am confused: why isn't the arm64 build faster on my iPhone X?

I read somewhere that 'The iPhone X’s processor is more powerful than the newest MacBook Pro' (2017), that can't be right. (My MacBook is 2015 I think.)

BTW, I use one external library, Device, to detect if a device is an iPhone X, and I tried using ios.add_libs=ExternalAccessory.framework.

**EDIT**

Some more information on the iOS ipa files:

32-bit Main.ipa 7.3 MB file: Mach-0 executable arm

64-bit Main.ipa 7.1 MB file: Mach-0 64-bit executable

On a 2012 iPad 4 only the 32-bit ipa installs. (The search task performance on a scale of 0-100 is 0.4.)
On an iPhone X both the 32-bit and 64-bit ipa's install, but there is no performance difference, which is odd.
The search task performance is 2.0, which is low compared to the Samsung Tab (7.0).

Comment: You should probably look at using [Metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) - You will get much better performance and lower energy consumption using the GPU rather than the CPU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> On the MacBook the search task is performed more than twice as slow in
> the simulator compared to a normal 64-bit JVM. Presumably this is
> because there is no (native) support for the functions Long.bitCount()
> and Long.numberOfTrailingZeros(), which I had to replace by (slower)
> code. Question: is there a way to improve this?

You can use a native interface and implement the JavaSE portion as the `Long.bitCount()` or `Long.numberOfTrailingZeros()`. This will work as fast on the simulator.

Another approach is to implement a Codename One API that does that natively to the important OS's and uses a simulation as a fallback for things you don't support. Then submit a PR to Codename One. You can do that by modifying `CodenameOneImplementation.java` with the fallback code then updating `JavaSEPort.java`, `AndroidImplementation.java`, `IOSImplementation.java` etc.

You would then expose these APIs somehow to the user which normally we do via Display but in this case might not be the ideal user API venue.

> There is no difference between the iPhone X armv7 and arm64 builds.
> How is this possible? (I tried removing the app and restarting the
> phone before installing the arm64 version. The current AppStore
> version is 32-bit, IIRC.)

64 bit is now required by apple so we no longer support building without it.

> The Android release version does a much better job on the search task than the debug version: 7 times faster!

These things are hard to tell. It could be the Android JIT which iOS doesn't allow or it could be a piece of code we failed to optimize. We would need to microbenchmark the resulting code to tell.

However, the JavaSE JIT is amazingly fast and will run circles around any native compilation benchmark we throw its way. That's just not something an AoT VM can compete with. We do have other advantages such as more consistent behavior and less hiccups when running.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am interested in optimizing Long.bitCount() and Long.numberOfTrailingZeros() but I don't understand how that should be implemented. 
Let's take Long.bitCount() for example, what would your first option look like?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by '64 bit is now required by apple so we no longer support building without it'. I am not interested in building without 64-bit, I am interested in the best 64-bit performance. I have edited my question to show more information on the 32-bit vs 64-bit builds. Do you agree that the 64-bit performance on the iPhone X is relatively poor? Is there a chance that an iOS AppStore build will be faster than a debug build? (Don't know how to test this.) If you want I can compile a representative test case for microbenchmarking.

Comment: You can't test 32bit code on a modern iOS device so both results will always be identical to the 64 bit result. Yes the performance isn't ideal for some cases. I suggest just sending a build with "include source" or using the ParparVM source code to translate your bytecode snippet. Then you can look at the resulting C code to see what was generated and if there's something we can do better.

Comment: I created a small performance test project and had a look at the generated Objective C code like you said. I am no expert in this area and I assume that the code will be compiled & optimized later. The code does raise a few questions, for example: is it necessary to declare local function variables as volatile? And to create a local variable for every parameter, first assign a value of zero to it and then the value of the parameter? Also, why are the calls to __CN1_DEBUG_INFO() also there in the AppStore build? That will slow down execution. Can I interest you in my performance test project?

Comment: Yes. Please file an issue and we can review this in a more organized way. A lot of these things are stripped by the compiler so local variables are mostly for convenience but don't cost much. The debug info is needed for stack traces to work. They exist even in production.

Comment: Thanks, I filed an issue, see https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3380. In the meantime, can you give me a clue or a link on how to use a native interface to implement Long.bitCount() and Long.numberOfTrailingZeros()?

Comment: Does this tutorial help?
https://www.codenameone.com/how-do-i---access-native-device-functionality-invoke-native-interfaces.html

Comment: Yes, thanks. I tried this with native implementations for JavaSE, iOS/Objective C (e.g. __builtin_popcount) and Android/Java. My benchmark (see issue) gets 15% faster on the MacBook/Simulator, 7% slower on the Samsung tablet and 30% slower on the iPhone X. So it seems there is no support (yet) on device hardware for popcount instructions etc. and there is native call overhead. Too bad but it was worth a shot.